# Comparing password from inputfield with database | Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to compare the password from the inputfield with the entry in the database. If the input from the user is correct he will get redirected. If its wrong nothing should happen.

I have this code in my Controller:

```
   public function check(check $check){

   if (User::where('password', '=', Input::get('password'))->exists()) {

      return redirect()->route('site.create');

   }

   Site::return($request->all());
}
```

And something like this stands in my view:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('please type in your password') }}</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
```

Thank you for every help i appreciate it.

Comment: Use Laravel's built-in `Auth` to handle users and passwords

Comment: I only want to check a password. I dont want to log in users

Comment: Are you inserting the passwords in database as it is or in hashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly compare passwords in Laravel. Passwords are one way hashed only.

```
Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword);
```

For more information https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing

```
$user =  User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();

if( Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password)){
//passwrd is equal

}
```

If you just want to check the passwrd you can use `Hash`

If you want to logged in users directly with password.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['password' => $password])) {
    // Password matches and logged in.
}
```

Comment: You're checking the email againts the password.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
if (Hash::check('yourpassword', Input::get('password'))) {
    return redirect()->route('site.create');
}
```

You can also use:

`password_verify()` in PHP. See this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php